# Unable to convert YOLOv4 to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, yolo, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use `yolo4` in my android project but I'm having problems with conversion.
The code from: https://pypi.org/project/yolov4/ has worked well on `Google-Colab`, though it had some problem with my `CUDA` version on `Jupyter` notebook.

I got conversion error from:

```py
yolo.save_as_tflite("yolov4.tflite")
```

Error was long and I am not sure which part I should paste here.

Can someone recommend some alternative method to convert `tflite` version of yolo4 (preferably working on `colab`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you would've posted important portion of the error, that would've been helpful. I'm guessing may be you're missing some dependencies/libraries.

Anyway to get `tflite` version of the `Yolov4`, I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite) repo.

**Install Dependencies:**

```
opencv-python==4.1.1.26
lxml
tqdm
tensorflow==2.3.0rc0
absl-py
easydict
matplotlib
pillow
```

**Download yolov4.weights file:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cewMfusmPjYWbrnuJRuKhPMwRe_b9PaT

Save `darknet` weights to `tfmodel` that's needed for `tflite` conversion:

```
python save_model.py --weights ./data/yolov4.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-416 --input_size 416 --model yolov4 --framework tflite
```

Convert to Yolov4 `tflite` version:

```
python convert_tflite.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-416 --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-416.tflite
```

Additionally to test the converted `tflite` model:

```
python detect.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-416.tflite --size 416 --model yolov4 --image ./data/kite.jpg --framework tflite
```

Comment: The second command does not work for me. "Converting unsupported operation: Softplus" Could it be a problem with my GPU or the version of tensorflow?

Comment: @freir96 As mentioned in the answer ensure you have installed all the dependencies with appropriate versions, especially note that you need `tensorflow==2.3.0rc0` for this to work. Also ensure that first command executes well without any error and produces corresponding outputs that's needed for second command to work. Note that this is all running on `CPU` only as we are using `tensorflow` and not `tensorflow-gpu`.