# Yolov4 weights conversion to tflite failure

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

I am using Google Colabs to convert Yolov4 darknet weights to tflite version.
I used  this [blog](https://blog.roboflow.com/training-yolov4-on-a-custom-dataset/) to train my own yolo detector and I got to acceptable accuracy for my detections.
Then I tried every repository on github [1](https://github.com/paroque28/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite),[2](https://github.com/paroque28/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite),[3](https://github.com/falahgs/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite-1) to covert my custom yolov4 weights to tflite version and I failed in each time. I faced the problem (can not reshape array) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005495/how-can-i-solve-reshape-valueerror-when-convert-yolov4-weights-to-tflite) and I solved it by modifying file.names and adjusting the change in the config file. In the end when I executed this code:
`!python convert_tflite.py --weights ./data/yolov4.weights --output ./data/yolov4.tflite`

I faced this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of node model_1/batch_normalization/AssignNewValue was passed float from model_1/batch_normalization/FusedBatchNormV3/ReadVariableOp/resource:0 incompatible with expected resource.

This problem was discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43833) but I couldn't find any solution
I am using google colab which make it easier with using the preinstalled libraries but maybe there could be some incomparability in libraries used in conversion ?
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Hi! Did you check these below  threads yet ?  https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/incompatible-with-expected-resource/72935    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43833        https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/converting-a-custom-darknet-model-to-tensorflow-lite-ffdd48d58082